# Return a count of every edge type leaving a node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a node with several types of outbound edges, let's say of types `["A","B","C"]`, how would I use cypher to query a neo4j database to return the counts of every edge.

E.g. if I have a graph like

```
(n0:NODE) -[:A]- (n1:NODE)
(n0:NODE) -[:A]- (n2:NODE)
(n0:NODE) -[:B]- (n3:NODE)
(n1:NODE) -[:B]- (n2:NODE)
(n4:NODE) // No edges
```

Assuming these edges are all bidirectional, I would want the query to return

```
Node, count(A), count(B), count(C) 
n0,   2,        1,        0
n1,   1,        1,        0
n2,   1,        1,        0
n3,   0,        1,        0 
n4,   0,        0,        0
```

For all nodes with label `NODE`.

I'm using this right now, which is okay, but it puts all the different edge types on different rows, so I have to iterate through all of them in post processing to build out the table that I want:

```
MATCH (n:NODE) -[r]- ()
WHERE 
    type(r) in ["A", "B", "C"]
RETURN 
    id(n) as nid,
    type(r) as rtype, 
    count(r) as cnt
```

Is there a way to get these all in one row like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go. Since you want to have all the types of the data even if it is `0`, one option is:

```
MATCH (n:NODE)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(m:NODE)
WHERE 
    type(r) IN ["A", "B", "C"]
WITH 
    CASE type(r) WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cA, 
    CASE type(r) WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cB,
    CASE type(r) WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cC,
    n.key AS Node
RETURN Node, SUM(cA) AS countA, SUM(cB) AS countB, SUM(cC) AS countC
```

Which for sample data:

```
MERGE (n0:NODE {key:'n0'})
MERGE (n1:NODE {key:'n1'}) 
MERGE (n2:NODE {key:'n2'}) 
MERGE (n3:NODE {key:'n3'}) 
MERGE (n4:NODE {key:'n4'})    

MERGE(n0)-[:A]-(n1)
MERGE(n0)-[:A]-(n2)
MERGE(n0)-[:B]-(n3)
MERGE(n1)-[:B]-(n2)
```

Returns:

```
╒══════╤════════╤════════╤════════╕
│"Node"│"countA"│"countB"│"countC"│
╞══════╪════════╪════════╪════════╡
│"n0"  │2       │1       │0       │
├──────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│"n1"  │1       │1       │0       │
├──────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│"n2"  │1       │1       │0       │
├──────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│"n3"  │0       │1       │0       │
├──────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│"n4"  │0       │0       │0       │
└──────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

*Note that your approach in the question, will not return "n4" as it has no relationships and your query only match nodes with a relationship.